# AngularJS - Defining Components using .components() vs using TypeScript

Tags: angularjs, angular-components

I was exploring about AngularJS. I have seen components being defined using .components() method [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component) and being defined using type-script in many other places [example](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/angular4/angular4_components)

Is there any difference between the methods ? Which is the best/preferred/recommended method for creating components ?

[On a personal note I find type-script a bit ugly and irritating]

Comment: AngularJS != Angular, I suggest you look into the distinction as they are completely different frameworks.

Comment: Here is a friendly reminder:

Angular 1.x  == AngularJS; 
Angular 2+   == Angular